# Flask SQLAlchemy: (psycopg2.errors.AdminShutdown) terminating connection due to administrator command

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a pretty standard setup of flask, SQLAlchemy and an AWS RDS with Postgresql DB.

After changing RDS SSL certificates on a running system the application (flask) displayed the following exception and could not recover from it.

> (psycopg2.errors.AdminShutdown) terminating connection due to administrator command
>   SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly

I init the DB is this way (standard way):

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)
```

The above exception happened during a standard DB query:

```
r = MyModel.query.filter(foo == bar).all()
```

How can I make the DB connection self-recovering?

How can I catch this exception?

Comment: Try `pool_pre_ping=True` option while creating the db engine, see details [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#dealing-with-disconnects). Also check out the logs of your RDS db, this might indicate some other problem